# How to set up Android Emulator WITHOUT Google Play Services

Tags: android, intellij-idea

A client is asking me to make a version of my app to run on a device that won't ever have Google Play Services.

Is there any way to tell the Android Emulator to run the app without using GPS?

Then I can test the code to make sure it works on the clients device.

Answer (score 14):

Use a system Image that doesn't contain google APIs.

you will find two types of images as you can see in the photo .

the ones the contain it will be named Google Api system image 
, 
or you can use genymotion it comes with no google apis installed by default.

Also to be sure you can use this method to check if Google play services are installed

```
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {

    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i("MY TAG GCM", "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use genymotion emulator https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/ It is by default without Google service.