# Create Android Wear Emulator Without Google Play Services

Tags: android-emulator, google-play-services, wear-os, android-studio-2.3

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 and I need to test my app on an emulator without Google Play Services. I know that it was pretty easy to create one using the old device manager (as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100132/how-to-set-up-android-emulator-without-google-play-services) question), but I can't figure out how to do it with the new one.

The SDK Manager tells me that the system images that I want/need (API level 25) are installed:

- Android Wear Intel x86 Atom System Image
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image

At the "Select a system image" step for my new virtual device, only images with the Google APIs are presented under the "Recommended" tab. I've checked "x86 Images" and "Other Images" but no options without Google Play Services are to be found anywhere. I've also looked through all the settings options available at the "Verify Configuration" step without finding anything useful.

Does anyone know how to do this, or is it perhaps in fact no longer possible?

Comment: AFAIK, Google Play Services is required when you set up a development environment for Wearable Apps. See [Creating and Running a Wearable App](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) for more information. Also, this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25506889) might help.

Comment: Yeah. I checked out the links but couldn't find anything helpful. Thanks anyway!